# Number of possible outcomes in which at least one die shows $5$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Three dice are rolled. Find the number of possible outcomes in which at least one die shows $5$.

Now total outcomes are $6^3$. Now I have to add three cases such as one die shows $5$ out of $3$ dice + $2$ dice show $5$ out of $3$ + all dice shows $5$. How do I proceed for individual case?

Thanks

Comment: Instead, consider subtracting all the cases in which no five occurs. You could proceed the way you are doing currently, but it would be cumbersome to compute.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг nah i don't want to do in this way. i know this way

Comment: For example, suppose you want the outcomes in which exactly one five comes. Then, you choose the dice in which $5$ comes (in three ways), and then choose the numbers on the other dices such that they are not five. This is done in $3 \times 5^2 = 75$ ways. Similarly, you can do for the other cases.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thanks mate...

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Die is singular, dice is plural, and dices means to cut into small cubes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks for english lesson

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for getting exactly $r$ number of a specific face on $N$ dice with each die having $x$ unique faces is:

$$ \text{ number of permutations} = \left(\frac{N!}{r!(N-r)!}\right)(x-1)^{(N-r)}$$

for $3$ six sided dice this means, $N=3, x=6$.  For exactly one $5$ $r=1$, for exactly two fives $r=2$, for exactly three fives $r=3$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks! N.F. Taussig

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that seems to work.  Represent each die by a generating function (i.e. polynomial)

Since on each die there is only 1 outcome you want, a 5, there are five other outcomes you don't want.  Call the outcomes you want y, and those you don't want x.   The generating function for each die would then be $f(die)=5x+y$

Now multiply these functions to get the various outcomes:

$f(die1)*f(die2)*f(die3) = 125x^2 + 75x^2y + 15xy^2 + 1y^3$

You can read off the coefficients to see there are 125 permutations with no 5's rolled; 75 with just one 5 rolled (the coefficient to the y containing term), 15 with just two 5's rolled (the coefficient to the $y^2$ containing term) and only one roll with three 5's.

**caveat** my background in this area of math is very limited, so could be wrong that this approach can be generalized.  I've no source for this approach except just noodling on it and tested it on simple cases.